# setting first cell of first row in excel

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a line in c sharp for storing the first cell of the first row in a string after reading it.

it's something like:-

```
str=read(row[index]);
```

what is the exact statement in c sharp? Any help?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811664/set-cell-value-using-excel-interop

Comment: @COLDTOLD yeah..i can read it...but i want to store the index in a string...so dat i can call cells like str[1], str[6] like that. How do i set the index? My excel file has several rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

private static string ReadSpreadsheet()
        {

            Workbook wb = null;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\APathToExcelSpreadsheet.xls", false, true);

            //Get the values in the sheet
            Range rng = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange;
            object[,] values;
            if (rng.Value2.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                values = (object[,])rng.Value2;
            }
            else
            {
                values = new object[2, 2];
                values[1, 1] = rng.Value2;
            }


            for (int row = 1; row <= values.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 1; col <= values.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
                {
                    if (values[row, col] != null)
                    {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read it by using excel interop by first including its refrence from office12 or office14 folder in your c drive if ms office is installed in your pc or in visualstudio folder after importing refrences here is the code

```
public static void GetExcelData(string _path)
    {



        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel._Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(_path);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;



        string firstcell == (xlRange.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();


        xlWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xlApp.Quit();



    }
```